# Why and 1 ( &1) bitwise operation always return 0 or 1

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I just started learning about bit wise operation and want to ask why and 1 ( &1) bitwise operation always return 0 or 1 .

Comment: What do you mean by "1 ( &1) bitwise operation"?

Comment: I mean any number when and with 1 just return 0 or 1 value ( a & 1 )

Comment: What else do you expect it to return? `x & 1` returns `1` if the least significant bit of `x` is `1` else `0`. `1 & 1 = 1`, `0 & 1 = 0`. That's how the operator is defined.

Comment: Any bit except the last one is 0 because it's 0 in 1. And the last one is the same than in a. That's all.

Comment: Any number or just 1 and 0?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's immediately answered by any documentation on the topic

Comment: 4 and *any number* will NEVER be 5 ... only 4 or 0

Comment: Understood, thank for your help

Comment: 3 is little more complex with & .... you can end up with 0, 1, 2 or 3 ... with 5 you can end up with 0, 1, 4 or 5 ... with 128, only 0 or 128 ... do you need any more examples?

Comment: @Denys Séguret: I just noticed the [javascript] tag on this question. It's not even a JavaScript question lol.

Answer (score 12):

```
0 & 0 === 0
0 & 1 === 0
1 & 0 === 0
1 & 1 === 1
```

therefore any number & 1 will always be either 0 or 1

in binary ... any number

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx0
```

or

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx1
```

where x can be 0 or 1

1 in binary is

```
00000000000001
```

so

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx1 &
00000000000001 ==
00000000000001

xxxxxxxxxxxxx0 &
00000000000001 ==
00000000000000
```

Answer (score 4):

When you perform `a & 1` it will always return 0 or 1 depending upon the the last binary digit of a.

Rules:

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

For example:

```
a = 5 //5 = 0101
b = a & 1  = 1 //(0101 & 0001)


a = 6 //6 = 0110
b = a  & 1 = 0 //(0110 & 0001)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bitwise operation. Suppose you take 2 & 1. That would be 10 and 01 in binary. Bitwise AND will give 00. BitWise operations with 1 will give 1 or 0 always because 1 has only a significant unit's place in binary. So it cannot return any value other than a 0 or a 1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to check if an integer is odd or even, returning a 0 for False and 1 for True.

## is_odd: 1 for odd , 0 for even

odd = number & 1

## is_even: 1 for even , 0 for odd

even = number & 1 ^ 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).